# Submit Button Not Working on Boostrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, submit

I have a form in Bootstrap 3 that's inside a modal. There's a button called "submit" where when it's clicked the stuff that was entered in the form should be sent to the database. Although when I click "Submit" nothing happens.

Here is a live preview: http://rentmycar.pe.hu/index.html

```html
<!--Checkout Modal Start -->

<div class = "modal fade" id = "checkoutModal" tabindex = "-1" role = "dialog" aria-labelledby = "checkoutModalLabel" aria-hidden = "true" data-backdrop = "static">

 <div class = "modal-dialog">

  <div class = "modal-content">

   <form action = "index.html" method = "post" id = "checkout-form" name = "checkout-form">



    <!--Modal header start -->

    <div class = "modal-header">

     <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal" aria-hidden = "true">&times;

     </button>

     <h4 class = "modal-title" id = "myModalLabel">Complete reservation</h4>

    </div>

    <!--Modal header end -->



    <!--Modal body start -->

    <div class = "modal-body">



     <!--Checkout Info start -->

     <div class = "checkout-info-box">

             <h3><i class = "fa fa-info-circle"></i> Upon completing this reservation enquiry, you will receive::</h3>

       <p>Your rental voucher to produce on arrival at the rental desk and a toll-free customer support number.</p>

           </div>

     <!--Checkout Info end -->



     <!--Checkout Rental Info start -->

     <div class = "checkout-vehicle-info">

      <div class = "location-date-info">

       <h3>Location & Date</h3>

       <div class = "info-box">

        <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

        <h4 class = "info-box-title">Pick-Up Time</h4>

        <p class = "info-box-description"><span id = "pick-up-date-ph"></span> at <span id = "pick-up-time-ph"></span></p>

        <input type = "hidden" name = "pick-up" id = "pick-up" value = "">

       </div>

       <div class = "info-box">

        <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

        <h4 class = "info-box-title">Drop-Off Time</h4>

        <p class = "info-box-description"><span id = "drop-off-date-ph"></span> at  <span id = "drop-off-time-ph"></span></p>

        <input type = "hidden" name = "drop-off" id = "drop-off" value = "">

       </div>

       <div class = "info-box">

        <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>

        <h4 class = "info-box-title">Pick-Up Location</h4>

        <p class = "info-box-description" id = "pickup-location-ph"></p>

        <input type = "hidden" name = "pickup-location" id = "pickup-location" value = "">

       </div>

       <div class = "info-box">

        <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>

        <h4 class = "info-box-title">Drop-Off Location</h4>

        <p class = "info-box-description" id = "dropoff-location-ph"></p>

        <input type = "hidden" name = "dropoff-location" id = "dropoff-location" value = "">

       </div>

      </div>



      <div class = "vehicle-info">

       <h3>CAR: <span id = "selected-car-ph"></span></h3> <a href = "#vehicles" class = "scroll-to">[Vehicle Models]</a>

       <input type = "hidden" name = "selected-car" id = "selected-car" value = "">

       <div class = "clearfix"></div>

       <div class = "vehicle-image">

        <img class = "img-responsive" id = "selected-vehicle-image" src = "#" alt = "Vehicle">

       </div>

      </div>



      <div class = "clearfix"></div>



     </div>

     <!--Checkout Rental Info end -->



     <hr>



     <!--Checkout Personal Info start -->

     <div class = "checkout-personal-info">

      <div class = "alert hidden" id = "checkout-form-msg">

       test

      </div>

      <h3>PERSONAL INFORMATION</h3>

      <div class = "form-group left">

       <label for = "first-name">First Name:</label>

       <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "first-name" id = "first-name" placeholder = "Enter your first name">

      </div>

      <div class = "form-group right">

       <label for = "last-name">Last Name:</label>

       <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "last-name" id = "last-name" placeholder = "Enter your last name">

      </div>

      <div class = "form-group left">

       <label for = "phone-number">Phone Number:</label>

       <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "phone-number" id = "phone-number" placeholder = "Enter your phone number">

      </div>

      <div class = "form-group right age">

       <label for = "age">Age:</label>

       <div class = "styled-select-age">

        <select name = "age" id = "age">

         <option value = "18">18</option>

         <option value = "19">19</option>

         <option value = "20">20</option>

         <option value = "21">21</option>

         <option value = "22">22</option>

         <option value = "23">23</option>

         <option value = "24">24</option>

         <option value = "25">25</option>

         <option value = "26">26</option>

         <option value = "27">27</option>

         <option value = "28">28</option>

         <option value = "29">29</option>

         <option value = "30">30</option>

         <option value = "31">31</option>

         <option value = "32">32</option>

         <option value = "33">33</option>

         <option value = "34">34</option>

         <option value = "35">35</option>

         <option value = "36">36</option>

         <option value = "37">37</option>

         <option value = "38">38</option>

         <option value = "39">39</option>

         <option value = "40">40</option>

         <option value = "41">41</option>

         <option value = "42">42</option>

         <option value = "43">43</option>

         <option value = "44">44</option>

         <option value = "45">45</option>

         <option value = "46">46</option>

         <option value = "47">47</option>

         <option value = "48">48</option>

         <option value = "49">49</option>

         <option value = "50">50</option>

         <option value = "51">51</option>

         <option value = "52">52</option>

         <option value = "53">53</option>

         <option value = "54">54</option>

         <option value = "55">55</option>

         <option value = "56">56</option>

         <option value = "57">57</option>

         <option value = "58">58</option>

         <option value = "59">59</option>

         <option value = "50">50</option>

         <option value = "61">61</option>

         <option value = "62">62</option>

         <option value = "63">63</option>

         <option value = "64">64</option>

         <option value = "65">65</option>

         <option value = "66">66</option>

         <option value = "67">67</option>

         <option value = "68">68</option>

         <option value = "69">69</option>

         <option value = "70">70</option>

         <option value = "71">71</option>

         <option value = "72">72</option>

         <option value = "73">73</option>

         <option value = "74">74</option>

         <option value = "75">75</option>

         <option value = "76">76</option>

         <option value = "77">77</option>

         <option value = "78">78</option>

         <option value = "79">79</option>

         <option value = "80">80</option>

         <option value = "81">81</option>

         <option value = "82">82</option>

         <option value = "83">83</option>

         <option value = "84">84</option>

         <option value = "85">85</option>

         <option value = "86">86</option>

         <option value = "87">87</option>

         <option value = "88">88</option>

         <option value = "89">89</option>

         <option value = "90">90</option>

         <option value = "91">91</option>

         <option value = "92">92</option>

         <option value = "93">93</option>

         <option value = "94">94</option>

         <option value = "95">95</option>

         <option value = "96">96</option>

         <option value = "97">97</option>

         <option value = "98">98</option>

         <option value = "99">99</option>

         <option value = "100">100</option>

        </select>

       </div>

      </div>

      <div class = "form-group left">

       <label for = "email-address">Email:</label>

       <input type = "email" class = "form-control" name = "email-address" id = "email-address" placeholder = "Enter your email address">

      </div>

      <div class = "form-group right">

       <label for = "email-address-confirm">Confirm Email Address:</label>

       <input type = "email" class = "form-control" name = "email-address-confirm" id = "email-address-confirm"  placeholder = "Confirm your email address">

      </div>

      <div class = "clearfix"></div>

     </div>

     <!--Checkout Personal Info end -->



     <!--Checkout Address Info start -->

     <div class = "checkout-address-info">

      <div class = "form-group address">

       <label for = "address">Address</label>

       <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "address" id = "address" placeholder = "Enter your Street an No.">

      </div>

      <div class = "form-group city">

       <label for = "city">City</label>

       <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "city" id = "city" placeholder = "Enter your City">

      </div>

      <div class = "form-group zip-code">

       <label for = "zip-code">Zip Code</label>

       <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "zip-code" id = "zip-code" placeholder = "Enter your Zip Code">

      </div>

      <div class = "clearfix"></div>

     </div>

     <!--Checkout Address Info end -->



     <div class = "newsletter">

      <div class = "form-group">

       <div class = "checkbox">

        <input id = "check1" type = "checkbox" name = "newsletter" value = "yes">

        <label for = "check1">Please send me latest news and updates</label>
                                

       </div>

      </div>



     </div>

    </div>

                

    <!--Modal body end -->



    <!--Modal footer start -->

    <div class = "modal-footer">

     <span class = "btn-border btn-gray">

      <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default btn-gray" data-dismiss = "modal">Cancel</button>

     </span>

     <span class = "btn-border btn-yellow">

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-yellow">Reserve now</button>

     </span>

    </div>

    <!--Modal footer end -->



   </form>

  </div>

 </div>

</div>

<!--Checkout Modal end -->
```

Comment: Where is your code? I suggest checking [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: did you put `button(type="submit") Submit`

Answer (score 0):

You can change this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-yellow">Reserve now</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-yellow" value="Reserve now">
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, here's a live preview: http://rentmycar.pe.hu/ , when you click reserve now, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Change the href from #teaser to something:

```
<a href="reservenow.php?new_reserve=true" class="reserve-button scroll-to"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Reserve now</a>
```

And your reservenow.php should look somathing like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['new_reserve'])) {
    reservenow();
}
function reservenow() {
....some sql updates here...
}?>
```